# how to restore mysql innoDb databases from programData file

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have reinstalled mysql. I already backed up mysql data in programData folder. Now I want to restore all the databases from that file. I don't want to mess around and try things for it. Do I have just to copy the backed up file into my new mysql Data folder? I have copied my database file(containing .frm and .ibd files) along with ib* files but after that my server didn't start again. I don't have deep understanding of what is going on back there.
Please let me know how to do that correctly.

I am using mysql 5.7 version

Comment: It's hard for people who don't know how MySQL works to restore databases by moving files around. There are lots of things that can go wrong with this approach. Did you `chown -R mysql:mysql .` in the datadir? The files are probably not read/write by mysqld. Look in the error log for more clues. Next time you should use a real backup & restore tool, not just move files around.

Comment: I did chwon -R mysql and that fixed it. Thank you for your helpful comment. I will sure have my database backed up very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the file ownership and permissions.

Files under the MySQL datadir must be readable and writeable by the uid of the mysqld process. This is typically a uid "mysql" (since everyone agreed years ago that running daemons as root is not a good idea). There is also a gid "mysql" on default installations.

The fix is therefore:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql <datadir>
```